# ArcGIS Data Reviewer installation problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, installation, extensions, data-reviewer

I have untypical problem connected with Data Reviewer extension installation. On new computer, with fresh Windows 7 installation there is no possibility to install Data Reviewer extension in correct way:

- Installation is finishing with the information "ArcGIS Data Reviewer 10 has been successfully installed." (no information about any installation errors)
- Extension is not visible in ArcGIS Customize->Extensions window, Data Reviewer toolbar don't exist as ArcGIS toolbar.

Installed apps:

- ArcGIS 10.0 (SP5)
- Data Reviewer 10 (SP5 + Patch2)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: Since that's a supported configuration. it's probably incorrect to state "there is no possibility to install Data Reviewer extension", though describing it as "untypical" is probably correct.  GIS SE is not supposed to replace Esri Tech support; I would recommend you contact Esri.  But first reboot your machine, and check on extension status again.

Comment: Vince, thanks for answer. I did both things: reboot and contact with ESRI support. No solution for now. I asked on GIS SE hoping, that maybe someone had similar problem connected with ESRI extensions.

Comment: Uninstall everything. Install in this order. Desktop 10 > DataReviewer (that comes with arcgis desktop media) > Desktop SP5 > DR (SP5 + Patch2)

Comment: I did it, uninstalled everything, and installed ArcGIS/DR/Patches in suggested order. All the time extenstion is not visible in ArcGIS. One thing, DR this is not the part of ArcGIS desktop media. Extensions which can be installed with ArcGIS (like 3D Analyst) are visible and working ok.

Comment: @Peter , probably the versions of your agis desktop and DR don't match. I am using DR since version 10 of ArcGIS.

Comment: @Farid, version is the same - I'm using DR from three years on other computer with ArcGIS 10. Like I mentioned, I'm trying to install DR on new computer with fresh Windows 7 installation.